# Node mongoose embedded document array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have my sample userSchema here:

```
{
    "_id": objectId("6092076ba811e50b565497ec"),
    "username": "test@gmail.com",
    "address_book": [{
        "_id": objectId("6092b1120f7e370b954a2708"),
        "address": "address1",
        "address2": "address2",
    }, {
        "_id": objectId("6093edcb88796b0a5eba19a3"),
        "address": "test1",
       "address2": "test2",
    }]
}
```

Can I find user by
`objectId("6092076ba811e50b565497ec")` and `address_book._id object("6093edcb88796b0a5eba19a3")`

and it return only the `address_book` that I selected? my expected return data should look like this

```
{
    "_id": objectId("6092076ba811e50b565497ec"),
    "username": "test@gmail.com",
    "address_book": {
        "_id": objectId("6093edcb88796b0a5eba19a3"),
        "address": "test1",
       "address2": "test2",
    }
}
```

here is my sample function

```
let user = [];
await User.findOne({
   _id: id,
   "address_book._id": address_id,
 })
.then((result) => {
   console.log(result);
   user = result;
 })
 .catch((err) => console.log(err));
 return user;
```

with this I get all address_book

and also can is there and updateOrCreate function by `address_book._id`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post your try or any problem you phased in your question.

Comment: I just updated my post. maybe this will help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation operators in find method starting from MongoDB 4.4,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `address_book` array and match `_id` condition
- `$first` to select first element from above filtered result

```
await User.findOne({
  _id: id,
  "address_book._id": address_id
},
{
  username: 1,
  address_book: {
    $first: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$address_book",
        cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(address_id)] }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5gqjcpvJUF9)

Comment: this doesnt return any address book. only username,_id and empty array on address_book

Comment: you need to convert string address_id to object id using mongoose.Types.ObjectId, see updated answer.

Comment: It WORK!!!! Thank you so much for you time. LONG LIVE BROTHER..

Answer (score 1):

[elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) is what you are looking for according to me. elemMatch for projection not just the match.

```
    db.<collection name>.find({
  < search using elem match >
}, {
  games: {
    $elemMatch: {
      //put your projection piece here, whatever selective what you want, check the example on documentation
      score: {
        $gt: 5
      }
    }
  },
  //anything else that you would want apart from within array projection
})
```

Update :

Data

```
    [
  {
    "_id": "6092076ba811e50b565497ec",
    "username": "test@gmail.com",
    "address_book": [
      {
        "_id": "6092b1120f7e370b954a2708",
        "address": "address1",
        "address2": "address2",
        
      },
      {
        "_id": "6093edcb88796b0a5eba19a3",
        "address": "test1",
        "address2": "test2",
        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Command

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  address_book: {
    $elemMatch: {
      address: "test1"
    }
  }
})
```

Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "6092076ba811e50b565497ec",
    "address_book": [
      {
        "_id": "6093edcb88796b0a5eba19a3",
        "address": "test1",
        "address2": "test2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YjM3qZuHi1F)

Comment: It still return all address_book with elemMatch

Comment: @pedopedo what are saying? I am updating the answer with proper example.

Comment: still result show all address_book list.
this is my code look like
const user = await User.findOne().elemMatch("address_book", {
    _id: address_id,
  });

Comment: @pedopedo Check the example, the playground. I am asking you to use elemMatch while doing projection, there is the MongoDB command right there in answer. What you have written in the commend is not correct.